Write two pandas dataframe to two different sheets in an excel in a directory in ADLS using databricks notebook
First of all, I tried writing directly to a blob. But that didn't work. So, I tried writing to a temp directory and then moving the file to the required directory. Even this didn't work. I am looking for a solution to write excels with multiple sheets to Azure Blob.
filename = os.path.join(arg_dict['out_dir'], old_attribute_file_path.replace(old_attribute_file_path.split('/')[-1].split('-')[-1].split('.')[0], attribute_files[0].split('-')[1]))

temp_file_name = os.path.join(TMP_PATH, old_attribute_file_path.replace(old_attribute_file_path.split('/')[-1].split('-')[-1].split('.')[0], attribute_files[0].split('-')[1]))

fill_color = PatternFill(start_color='FFFF00', end_color='FFFF00', fill_type='solid')

# Write DataFrames to Excel
with pd.ExcelWriter(temp_file_name, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    df2.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Sheet2')
    
    # Load the workbook
    workbook = writer.book

    # Save the workbook
    workbook.save(temp_file_name)

shutil.move(temp_file_name, filename)

The error that I get ->
File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-6a81eac8-0226-477b-9715-070566214b43/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py:294, in save_workbook(workbook, filename)
    292 workbook.properties.modified = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    293 writer = ExcelWriter(workbook, archive)
--> 294 writer.save()
    295 return True

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-6a81eac8-0226-477b-9715-070566214b43/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py:275, in ExcelWriter.save(self)
    273 def save(self):
    274     """Write data into the archive."""
--> 275     self.write_data()
    276     self._archive.close()

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-6a81eac8-0226-477b-9715-070566214b43/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py:60, in ExcelWriter.write_data(self)
     57 archive = self._archive
     59 props = ExtendedProperties()
---> 60 archive.writestr(ARC_APP, tostring(props.to_tree()))
     62 archive.writestr(ARC_CORE, tostring(self.workbook.properties.to_tree()))
     63 if self.workbook.loaded_theme:

File /usr/lib/python3.10/zipfile.py:1816, in ZipFile.writestr(self, zinfo_or_arcname, data, compress_type, compresslevel)
   1814 zinfo.file_size = len(data)            # Uncompressed size
   1815 with self._lock:
-> 1816     with self.open(zinfo, mode='w') as dest:
   1817         dest.write(data)

File /usr/lib/python3.10/zipfile.py:1182, in _ZipWriteFile.close(self)
   1180     self._fileobj.seek(self._zinfo.header_offset)
   1181     self._fileobj.write(self._zinfo.FileHeader(self._zip64))
-> 1182     self._fileobj.seek(self._zipfile.start_dir)
   1184 # Successfully written: Add file to our caches
   1185 self._zipfile.filelist.append(self._zinfo)

OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported


openpyxl and xlsxwriter are both used for pandas dataframes. You can use the spark plugin to write to excel directly to blob storage
You can install this on the cluster level like so

And you code will look like this.
First get your access key and set it as a spark config.
spark.conf.set(
    "fs.azure.account.key.<storage_name>.dfs.core.windows.net",
    dbutils.secrets.get(scope=<scope_name>, key=<access_key>))

Next, set the path and write your spark dataframes to the same path but different worksheets.
path = "abfss://<container_name>@<storage_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/testdir/test.xlsx"  

spark_Df1.write.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")\
  .option("header", "true")\
  .option("dataAddress", "'My Sheet1'!A1")\
  .mode("append")\
  .save(path)

spark_Df2.write.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")\
  .option("header", "true")\
  .option("dataAddress", "'My Sheet2'!A1")\
  .mode("append")\
  .save(path)


PySpark dataframes lack a to_excel method and databricks does not enable converting PySpark dataframes to Excel files.
The solution is to Save the file in  databricks/drivers. Then move the file and delete it from drivers.
with pd.ExcelWriter(r'export2.xlsx', engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    #file will be written to /databricks/driver/ i.e., local file system
    data.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    data2.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Sheet2')
    workbook = writer.book

    # Save the workbook
    workbook.save('export2.xlsx')

Here you can see file got stored in the drivers folder:

Then move the file from drivers to DBFS folders:
from shutil import move
move('/databricks/driver/export2.xlsx','/dbfs/export2.xlsx')


This didn’t work for me for some reason. However, I’ve found a solution. Instead of writing the file to dbfs/tmp, writing to /tmp and then moving the file to Azure Blob worked.
